# Android: EditText внутри ScrollView. Ошибка: слишком длинный EditText (много строк)

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-scrollview, scrollview, edittext

Столкнулся с неожиданной проблемой, вот в чем суть:

Есть элемент EditText, куда будет вводиться многострочный текст, и есть необходимость в том, чтобы введенный текст плавно прокручивался. Сам EditText может прокручивать текст, но делает это не плавно, поэтому я обернул его в ScrollView:

```
<ScrollView
  ...>
    <EditTExt
      .../>
</ScrollView>
```

Все работает, как надо. Однако, когда введенный текст превышает 1039 строк, в лог начинают сыпаться ошибки. Текст ошибки очень большой, но вот с чего он начинается:

> this size is invalid ,this =
> androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{dec24db VFED..CL. .F....ID
> 15,15-1065,65671 #7f09019d app:id/myText aid=1073741825} ,and the
> mMeasuredWidth = 1050 ,and the mMeasuredHeight = 65593
>
> ...

Ошибки приходят при загрузке элемента и при добавлении/удалении новых строк. Однако, если в тексте 1039 строк и меньше, все снова становится нормально.
Если убрать ScrollView, то ошибки пропадают, как и плавная прокрутка текста, конечно.

Как я понял, проблема в том, что ScrollView вмещает EditText, как элемент во всю высоту, и он просто становится слишком большим. При этом, работе приложения ошибка не мешает, и даже если добавить в несколько раз больше строк, ничего не крашится и не тормозит. Но есть опасение, что это может зависеть от устройства, прошивки и т.д., и в перспективе грозит стать проблемой. Здесь важно отметить, что мне не нужно, чтобы EditText вмещал миллионы строк и был километровым в высоту, понятно, что у всего есть пределы, но не могут же быть они настолько маленькими.

Сам я вижу несколько векторов решения:

1. Пытаться как-то настроить ScrollView и EditText. Перепробовал уже менять/добавлять/удалять различные атрибуты, ничего пока не меняется.
2. Отказаться от ScrollView и пытаться реализовать плавную прокрутку как-то иначе, возможно есть какие-то аналоги EditText, или дополнительные библиотеки, хз.
3. Забить на эти ошибки, пока все работает. Этот вариант мне не нравится, но ни чтение документации, ни гугление пока ничего не дает.

Собственно, вот. Что посоветуете с этим делать? Может я неправильно понял проблему?

**UPD** Да, судя по всему, проблема действительно в размере элемента. Если вручную ввести, например android:layout_height="100000dp" у элемента, то начинают сыпаться те же ошибки.
Так же тестировал на эмуляторе, на 10 Андроиде такой ошибки нет, а на 13 есть.

Comment: попробуйте использовать `NestedScrollView`

Comment: С NestedScrollView поведение такое же

Comment: может быть тогда ограничить макс строк? например до 30. тогда будет прокрутка

Comment: Если вы имеете ввиду атрибут android:maxLines у EditText, то да, это сработает, но это решение проблемы с обратной стороны. Хотелось бы иметь возможность вводить хотя бы 5000-10000 строк